# How to set UserID and Password in Progress Developer Studio 11.5

Tags: passwords, progress-4gl, openedge, userid

I am fairly new to progress. I am currently using Progress Developer Studio 11.5. Does any one know how to set UserID and Password. Any documentation would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete documentation for 11.5 is available here...

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/openedge_general/w/openedgegeneral/2352.openedge-11-5-product-documentation.aspx

Setting the userid and password for DB at connection time is handled by the -U and -P options.

Setting it from code uses the SETUSERID function.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation.